# How to allow only a group of IPs access the site from code behind using ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this website where I want just only the computers in our office have access to it. How can I write code to do this? I've been looking all over the web but I couldn't find anything like this.

Sorry I couldn't write any code about this before posting this question.

I will be using this part of code in the header.aspx file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an IP-blocker http module, don't ever do such a thing in the codebehind.
Of course, instead of banning a list listed in web.config, you need to ban anything that doesn't start with 192.168 or 10. or whatever you use internally.

**VB.NET**:

```vb
Imports System.Web

' http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308000
' http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hemantkathuria/ASPNetHttpModules11262005004251AM/ASPNetHttpModules.aspx
' http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm
' http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/prjaspxmod/ASPNET_HTTP_Modules_168.aspx
' http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx
' http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2009071801&page=1
' http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6962/1954
' http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/59731.aspx


Public Class IPbanning
    Implements IHttpModule

    Private Shared m_scIPadresses As System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection = FillBlockedIps()

    Public Sub Dispose() Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Dispose
    End Sub

    Public Sub Init(ByVal context As System.Web.HttpApplication) Implements System.Web.IHttpModule.Init
        AddHandler context.BeginRequest, New EventHandler(AddressOf context_BeginRequest)
        'AddHandler context.EndRequest, New EventHandler(AddressOf IHttpModule_Dispose)
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Checks the requesting IP address in the collection
    ''' and block the response if it's on the list.
    ''' </summary>
    Private Sub context_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)

        Dim strIP As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress

        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(strIP) Then
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<h1>Server-Error: IP is NULL</h1>")
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
            Exit Sub
        End If

        If strIP = "127.0.0.2" Then
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<h1 style=""color: blue;""><font color=""red"">YOU</font> (" + HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString() + ") are banned.</h1>")
            'HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
        End If

        If (m_scIPadresses.Contains(strIP)) Then
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End()
        End If
    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Retrieves the IP addresses from the web.config
    ''' and adds them to a StringCollection.
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <returns>A StringCollection of IP addresses.</returns>
    Private Shared Function FillBlockedIps() As System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection

        Dim scIPcollection As System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection = New System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection()
        'Dim strRaw As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("blockip")
        Dim strRaw As String = "44.0.234.122, 23.4.9.231"
        strRaw = strRaw.Replace(",", ";")
        strRaw = strRaw.Replace(" ", ";")

        For Each strIP As String In strRaw.Split(";")
            scIPcollection.Add(strIP.Trim())
        Next

        Return scIPcollection
    End Function
End Class
```

**C#**:

```cs
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;

// http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308000
// http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/hemantkathuria/ASPNetHttpModules11262005004251AM/ASPNetHttpModules.aspx
// http://www.15seconds.com/issue/020417.htm
// http://www.worldofasp.net/tut/prjaspxmod/ASPNET_HTTP_Modules_168.aspx
// http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlers.aspx
// http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2009071801&page=1
// http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6962/1954
// http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/59731.aspx

public class IPbanning : IHttpModule
{

    private static System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection m_scIPadresses = FillBlockedIps();

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }

    public void Init(System.Web.HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
        //AddHandler context.EndRequest, New EventHandler(AddressOf IHttpModule_Dispose)
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Checks the requesting IP address in the collection
    /// and block the response if it's on the list.
    /// </summary>

    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strIP = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress;

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(strIP)) {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<h1>Server-Error: IP is NULL</h1>");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
            return;
        }

        if (strIP == "127.0.0.2") {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<h1 style=\"color: blue;\"><font color=\"red\">YOU</font> (" + HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress.ToString() + ") are banned.</h1>");
            //HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }

        if ((m_scIPadresses.Contains(strIP))) {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = 403;
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieves the IP addresses from the web.config
    /// and adds them to a StringCollection.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A StringCollection of IP addresses.</returns>
    private static System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection FillBlockedIps()
    {
        System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection scIPcollection = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
        //Dim strRaw As String = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("blockip")
        string strRaw = "44.0.234.122, 23.4.9.231";
        strRaw = strRaw.Replace(",", ";");
        strRaw = strRaw.Replace(" ", ";");

        foreach (string strIP in strRaw.Split(";")) {
            scIPcollection.Add(strIP.Trim());
        }

        return scIPcollection;
    }
}
```

PS: You can put the module into the asp.net solution, then you don't need to add a web.config entry:

Add it in **global.asax**:

**VB.NET**

```vb
Public Shared ThatModule As IHttpModule = New WebServiceAuthenticationModule()

' http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/44979.aspx
Public Overrides Sub Init()
    MyBase.Init()
    ThatModule.Init(Me)
End Sub
```

**C#**

```cs
public static IHttpModule ThatModule = new WebServiceAuthenticationModule();
// http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/44979.aspx
public override void Init()
{
    base.Init();
    ThatModule.Init(this);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are hosting this with IIS?

in IIS 6

Right click on the website, and Under 'Directory Security' You can Grant / Deny the ip addresses range you wish.

Comment: Though this answer would work great, the question was regarding doing it from code behind in .NET

Answer (score 2):

Well, the easiest way would be not to use code at all, but to implement the IP address restrictions in IIS, as darwindave suggests.

But if you want to code it: `Request.UserHostAddress` contains the IP address the request is coming from. Compare this to the IP-address or addresses you want to allow, and `Response.Redirect` to an error page if it doesn't match.

Comment: Also, if you want none of the site at all to be accessible, then put it in the Global.asax, rather than having to  put it in every handler/form

Answer (score 0):

I could do it via IPSec, right-click advanced on the NIC, and look for something called IpSec.. there you can filter the NIC to only talk to certain IP Addresses.